# Select row on gridview using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery function below:

```
$("[id*=gridView1] td").on("click", function () {
    var row = $(this).parent();
    $("[id*=gridView1] tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0] != row[0]) {
            $("td", this).removeClass("gridView1_selectedRow");
        }
    });

    var done = 0;
    $("td", row).each(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("gridView1_selectedRow")) {
        $(this).addClass("gridView1_selectedRow");
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass("gridView1_selectedRow");
        }
    });
});
```

What it does is it will add a css class on the selected row, adding highlight.

My problem is I don't want my user to highlight or select the last row of my gridview because it will be a row of page number, not data row.

I tried using this:

```
 $("[id*=gridView1] tr:not(:last-child)")
```

But I ended up highlighting the whole gridview or all rows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your use of `[id*=gridView1] td` in your selectors is non standard. Instead you should be using something along the lines of `#gridView1 td`.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Presuming the OP is using ASP.NET it has a "nice" quality of not respecting at runtime the IDs you give elements. Usually I do something more like "[id$=gridView1]", but obviously you could give the element it's own class instead.

Comment: @DanielCook So this is an alternative to replacing jquery's `on` method with `live`?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Probably not. I don't understand your question. I'm just assuming the OP is using ASP.NET which they didn't specify. If they were that's an argument for using the kind of selector they used. [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `$("[id*=gridView1] tr:not(:last)")`?

It would make your entire script something like this:

```
$("[id*=gridView1] tr:not(:last)").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".gridView1_selectedRow").removeClass("gridView1_selectedRow");
    $(this).addClass("gridView1_selectedRow")
});
```

Comment: HAH! You bugger.. I literally just finish making my fiddle and you answer the question with exactly what I was going to do.. You can have it then! http://jsfiddle.net/5Tcgq/1/

Comment: @Mike I had also made almost the same exact fiddle. But yours is nice. Thanks for that.